# Is the textbook solution wrong by a sign? Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the Laurent series of $\frac{e^z}{z^2 -1}$ about $z = 1$.

Here is my solution:
Factor denominator
$\frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z+1)}$

let $w = z - 1$, and so $z = w + 1$, substitute in
$\frac{e^{w+1}}{w(w+2)}$

Do partial fraction decomposition to get rid of the exponential in numerator

$\frac{e^{w+1}}{w(w+2)}$ = $\frac{A}{w} + \frac{B}{w+2}$

$e^{w+1} = A(w+2) + Bw$

If $w=0$, $e=2A$, $A = e/2$. If $w = -2$, $\frac{1}{e} = -2B$, $B = \frac{-1}
{2e}$

Thus our new equation is 
$\frac{e}{2w} + \frac{-1}{2e(w+2)}$

Because the first term $\frac{e}{2w}$ is already in terms of $w = (z-1), we leave it be. The second term we can expand using geometric series expansion

$\frac{-1}{4e} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (\frac{-w}{2})}$

and so the Laurent series we get is

$$\frac{e}{2w} - \frac{1}{4e} \cdot \{1 - \frac{w}{2} + \frac{w^2}{4} - \frac{w^3}{8} ... \} $$

However, the textbook solution has same terms, but no negative sign. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Ummm… that's not a rational function… How could you do partial fraction decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You considered $e^{w+1}$ as a rational function (which is not!). Instead you should expand it at $w=0$ as
$$e^{w+1}=e\cdot e^w=e \left(1+w+\frac{w^2}{2}+\frac{w^3}{6}+\dots\right).$$ 
Hence, after decomposing the rational function $\frac{1}{w(w+2)}$,
$$\frac{e^{w+1}}{w(w+2)}=e^{w+1}\left(\frac{1}{2w} - \frac{1/4}{1+w/2}\right)\\=
e\left(1+w+\frac{w^2}{2}+\frac{w^3}{6}+\dots\right)\left(\frac{1}{2w} - \frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{w}{2}+\frac{w^2}{4}+\dots\right)\right).$$
Can you take it from here?
Finally the Laurent expansion should be
$$\frac{e}{2w} + \frac{e}{4} \left(1 + \frac{w}{2} + \frac{w^2}{12} +\dots\right).$$

Comment: So there's no way to avoid the tedious multiplication of series terms? Also why is $e^z$ not a rational function?

Comment: No. But  how many terms of the expansion do you need? A rational function is by definition a ratio of polynomials.

Comment: not alot , but would prefer to avoid it if possible.   Thank you.

Comment: In order to have the Laurent expansion up to $w^2$ you need the expansion of $e^w$ up to $w^3$.